# How to sort a DateTime elements

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime

I have as following:

Class Video, which contains among others a DateTime property (when a Video is posted).

Now I want to display few of recent videos added, i have a List of videos, and I am looking for lambda expressions to compare two DateTime elements

This doesn`t work:

```
List<Video> list = new List<Video>();
//.. Adding some videos
List<Video> orderedList = list.OrderBy(x => x.DatePosted).ToList();
```

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: What exactly not working? Can you clarify what is your actual results and what is your expected results?

Comment: List<Video> orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePosted).ToList(); should do

Comment: The code you described does work, as you can see at the bottom of this page: http://ideone.com/Gfan8o Please post your actual code that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the newest videos and [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get only your few videos:

```
const int aFew = 5;
var fewRecentVideos = list.OrderByDescending(v => v.DatePosted).Take(aFew);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list.OrderBy(x => (DateTime.Now - x.DatePosted).TotalMinutes).ToList( );
```

You can convert the DateTime into a TimeSpan relative to today/now and do either ascending or descending order.